# Single post template page not showing

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

This is my custom type

```
function cd_custom_post()
{
    // creo e registro il custom post type
    register_post_type('podcast', /* nome del custom post type */
        // definisco le varie etichette da mostrare nei menù
        array('labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Podcasts', /* nome, al plurale, dell'etichetta del post type. */
            'singular_name' => 'Podcast', /* nome, al singolare, dell'etichetta del post type. */
            'all_items' => 'All podcasts', /* testo nei menu che indica tutti i contenuti del post type */
            'add_new' => 'Add new', /*testo del pulsante Aggiungi. */
            'add_new_item' => 'Add new podcast', /* testo per il pulsante Aggiungi nuovo post type */
            'edit_item' => 'Edir podcast', /*  testo modifica */
            'new_item' => 'New podcast', /* testo nuovo oggetto */
            'view_item' => 'See all podcasts', /* testo per visualizzare */
            'search_items' => 'Find podcast', /* testo per la ricerca*/
            'not_found' => 'No podcast found', /* testo se non trova nulla */
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No podcast found in the recycle bin', /* testo se non trova nulla nel cestino */
            'parent_item_colon' => ''
        ), /* fine dell'array delle etichette del menu */
            'description' => 'Podcast', /* descrizione del post type */
            'public' => true, /* definisce se il post type sia visibile sia da front-end che da back-end */
            'publicly_queryable' => true, /* definisce se possono essere fatte query da front-end */
            'exclude_from_search' => false, /* esclude (false) il post type dai risultati di ricerca */
            'show_ui' => true, /* definisce se deve essere visualizzata l'interfaccia di default nel pannello di amministrazione */
            'query_var' => true,
            'menu_position' => 8, /* definisce l'ordine in cui comparire nel menù di amministrazione a sinistra */
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-playlist-audio', /* imposta l'icona da usare nel menù per il posty type */
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'podcast', 'with_front' => false), /* specificare uno slug per leURL */
            'has_archive' => 'false', /* definisci se abilitare la generazione di un archivio (tipo archive-cd.php) */
            'capability_type' => 'post', /* definisci se si comporterà come un post o come una pagina */
            'hierarchical' => false, /* definisci se potranno essere definiti elementi padri di altri */
            /* la riga successiva definisce quali elementi verranno visualizzati nella schermata di creazione del post */
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'sticky')
        ) /* fine delle opzioni */
    ); /* fine della registrazione */

}

// Inizializzo la funzione
add_action('init', 'cd_custom_post');
```

And this is the single podcast template page, called 'single-podcast.php'

```
<?php
/**
 *Template Name: Template Podcast Details
 *Template Post Type: podcast
 */
get_header();

$fields = get_post_custom();
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'podcast',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_per_page' => 1,
);
$testimonials = new WP_Query($args);
$postid = url_to_postid(get_permalink());
?>
<h1>Dettaglio podcast</h1>
```

Then i added a new page called Single Podcast, in wp-admin. But i'm not able to find the template page in the following voice: Page Attributes -> Template.
What am I doing wrong? The nomenclature? 
For example in my homepage i have all the post with the following code

```
    <a href="<?= the_permalink() ?>">
            <p><?= get_field('name-track') ?></p>
        </a>
```

And this is the url 'http://localhost/nojokeradio/podcast/pod-3/'

Answer (score 0):

Please change a Page Name from single-podcast.php to anything like podcast-display.php.

single-podcast.php is post template which display single post means when you will trying to visit any of the post from podcast post type that page will call so you can't assign template name to it. instead of that you can change name of your page anything like podcast.php or something else.

Comment: what did you put as page-name?

Comment: why are you creating this page? for displaying post content? means whenever you want visit single post from podcast post type?

Comment: For display the single post (podcast). Now it's podcast-details.php

Comment: okay than you don't need to create template for that. you already have single.php page in your wordpress theme folder which will display your post content.

Comment: but if you want to write your own code than create page single-podcast.php and do not mention template name in it and also don't need to create page in wordpress admin. just have to write your own code related to post. R u getting my point what I'm trying to say ?

Comment: It's a custom theme so i created single-podcast without mention template name but don't work

Comment: Ok if it is custom theme than create it using single.php. It will definitely work.

Comment: Yes, single.php work, but not single-{post-type}.php, strange. Now i restart the project, maybe i'll found the error. Thank you for your help

Comment: @DB please mark my answer right. or give upvote if my answer is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your new post type to have

```
'capability_type' => 'post',
```

You won't be able to use templates. Change that to

```
'capability_type'    => 'page',
```

Also don't forget to add support for 'page-attributes'

```
'supports'    => array('title', 'page-attributes'),
```

Comment: Perhaps try to change filename of this template to podcasts.php for example.

Comment: It gives me the same result

Answer (score 0):

What has been suggested by @Daniel Drabik should solve your problem.
Are using an old version of WordPress? The templates for Custom Post Types are supported starting from WordPress 4.7, as you can see here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Version_4.7
and here:
https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/11/03/post-type-templates-in-4-7/